# How to convert Linq to SQL to Linq Entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

hi I have the code below could you help me please to rewrite from LINq to SQL to Linq to Entity. thank you

```
if(account.AccountID > 0)
{
   dc.Accounts.Attach(account, true);
}
else
{
   dc.Accounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);
}

dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: have you tried? EF has Attach, InsertOnSubmit and SubmitChanges methods also. don't think you need to change anything.

Comment: For future reference this article helped me --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Change `InsertOnSubmit` to `Add`.

Change `SubmitChanges` to `SaveChanges`.

There is no `bool` argument needed for `Attach`.